# Set multiple styleClass values

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

How does one set two classes on a node in a JavaFX FXML file?

```
<VBox styleClass="notice high">
```

This adds one value `"notice high"` instead of two values `"notice"` and `"high"`. How can I add two values?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"Primitive type" lists can be seperated by ',' inside an attribute

```
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" styleClass="a, b">
```

Comment: In case of the spinner node the comma separated class list is interpreted as one class name. You must set it like this to get it working 
`<Spinner><styleClass><String fx:value="a" /><String fx:value="b" /></styleClass></Spinner>`